# CSS3 nth-of-type combined with a class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a page wrapper class called `.j-l-page-wrapper`. I have a section wrapper class called `.j-v-section-wrapper`. I would like for each section wrapper in the page wrapper to have alternating background colors. I have used the following CSS:

```
div.j-l-page-wrapper div.j-v-section-wrapper:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: @j-var-color-section-wrapper-bg-mod1;
}

div.j-l-page-wrapper div.j-v-section-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: @j-var-color-section-wrapper-bg-mod2;
}
```

along with HTML

```
<div class="j-l-page-wrapper">
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

However, no alternating background coloring is applied, leading me to think that I have not applied the correct selector.

How do I say, using CSS3, apply `even`/`odd` based background coloration to a `div` of one type containing a `div` of another type? Put another way, if my HTML were:

```
<div class="j-l-page-wrapper">
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="something-else"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="something-else"></div>
</div>
```

... I would still want the four `div`s of the specified type to have alternating colors.

Comment: Not with that HTML. As far as `:nth-of-type()` is concerned, the descendants are all divs.

Comment: Got it. So simply put, `:nth-of-type` does not care about my classes or IDs when it is counting, ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, with the second markup configuration you can't have the desired behaviour with CSS.

The  `div.YOUR_CLASS:nth-of-type()` counts all the div elements of same level. Adding a class to the selecor just makes sure the style is applied only to the elments with that class but it keeps counting all the divs that have the same level.

**Workaround :**

You can replace the tags with the class `.something-else` by an other tag (for example a `<span>` element) it will work as desired with `:nth-of-type()`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/bZB6g/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="j-l-page-wrapper">
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <span class="something-else"></span>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="j-v-section-wrapper"></div>
    <span class="something-else"></span>
</div>
```